# PHP syntax simplify

Tags: php

IN PHP I noticed that if we have code like below:

```
<?php if ( function('parameter')):?>
                  <?php //do something here ?>  
               <?php endif; ?>
```

why can't we write this code like:

```
<?php    if ( function('parameter'))
               //do something here  
               endif; ?>
```

I am new to PHP, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, it's redundant. Just bad coding. You'll see a lot of that in PHP, watch out for it!

Comment: You'd still need to `echo` those HTML elements though.

Comment: You just happened to pick the least convenient templating scheme to draw conclusions from. Also, no you can't do that. HTML literals are not supported by standard PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code has to be inside `<?php ?>` and the HTML markup needs to be outside. You can also print out the HTML markup with `echo`.

Here is an example (much cleaner in my opinion, than example 2). The HTML markup is inside a PHP string. The return value of `the_field()`, a string, is then concated with `.`:

```
<?php
    the_post_thumbnail('square');

    if(get_field('quote_url')) {
        echo '<p class="btn"><a href="'.the_field('quote_url');.'">Request a Quote</a></p>';
    }
    if(get_field('rfq_pdf_url')) {
        echo '<p class="btn"><a href="'.the_field('rfq_pdf_url');.'">Download PDF</a></p>';
    }
?>
```

And here is another valid example (2). You can end the PHP part with `?>` and output regular HTML markup and then start the PHP part again with `<?php`:

```
<?php
    the_post_thumbnail('square');

    if(get_field('quote_url')) { ?>
        <p class="btn"><a href="
        <?php the_field('quote_url'); ?>
        ">Request a Quote</a></p>
    <?php }
    if(get_field('rfq_pdf_url')) { ?>
        <p class="btn"><a href="
        <?php the_field('rfq_pdf_url');?>
        ">Download PDF</a></p>
    <?php }
?>
```

It would however be redundant to start with `<?php` on every line and end it then again with `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be:

```
<?php 
    the_post_thumbnail('square');
        if(get_field('quote_url')) {
?>       
            <p class="btn"><a href='<?php echo the_field('quote_url'); ?>'>Request a Quote</a></p>
<?php
        } 
        if(get_field('rfq_pdf_url')) {
?>
            <p class="btn"><a href="<?php the_field('rfq_pdf_url');?>"">Download PDF</a></p>
<?php
        }
?>
```